# AppleScript inserts string into application inbetween double quotes

Tags: applescript, double-quotes

I just purchased Alfred App for my Mac and I want to use this script I found online:

```
---------------------------------------------------
--Modified by: Pontus Sundén, http://psu.se
--Icon from: http://findicons.com/pack/1362/private_eye_act_1
---------------------------------------------------
on alfred_script(strQuery)
    --Get the parameters passed to the script - this is the search query
    set strSearchCriteria to SpaceList(strQuery)

    --Try to populated an existing window with the search query
    tell application "Evernote"
        try
            set query string of window 1 to strSearchCriteria
        on error
            --No existing window, open an new one
            open collection window with query string strSearchCriteria
        end try
    end tell
    tell application "System Events" to set frontmost of process "Evernote" to true
end alfred_script


--Take a list of text items and retrun them as a string with a space between each item
on SpaceList(astrItems)
    --Store what the current list delimiter is
    set tmpDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters

    --Set the list delimiter to a space and build the string we want to pass back
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
    set strReturn to astrItems as string

    --Set the list delimiter back to what it was previously
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tmpDelimiters

    --Return the string we built
    return strReturn
end SpaceList
```

which should open up evernote and search for something. It works fine, but instead of searching for, say the word boat, it will search for "boat" with the double quotes and obviously this yields no matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is perfectly correct – the spurious quoting of search terms passed via AppleScript is a **known Evernote bug** in version 3 of the client (well, “known” as in “I opened a support ticket for it a while ago, and Evernote acknowledged it”; I’d add a link to the ticket, but these are private to the user who opened it … will update on progress, though).

Until they get around to fix it, you will have to either use [the suggested GUI Scripting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872544/990363) as a workaround, or correct the search strings manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UI scripting to populate the search field like this:

```
set xxx to "boat"
activate application "Evernote"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Evernote"
    set value of text field 1 of group 4 of tool bar 1 of window 1 to xxx
end tell
```